# LookupRows between dates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to seek data extension row between some datetimes variables

Is this possible?

I could figure out how this is actually works... for example, if I got two rows with this datetime field: "12/29/2016 12:30:00 AM" and "12/29/2016 12:00:00 AM" and I try to Lookup by

> LookupRows(@DE, "DateEvent", FormatDate("12/29/2016", "YYYY/MM/DD"))

That function only return the row that contains "12/29/2016 12:00:00 AM" as DateEvent value but not return the other one...

How could I lookup every rows in that "day" (in that date) no matter what time?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not possible as previously discussed several times on SFSE.  Best bet is to do your date calculations or selection in a Query Activity prior to the send.